# My product grid is changing my layout of my site when I hover over it. How can I change this?

Tags: html, css

Currently for my site I am building a product grid that is supposed to show more information when you hover over it. But now when I hover over my product the layout of my site changes. How can I make it that it will show my information without changing the layout?

```css
.home-products {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
.product-image-home {
  height: 200px;
}
.product-grid {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 225px;
}

.product-grid h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.product-info p {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.product-overlay-button {
  background: #85bf31;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-grid:hover {
  width: 225px;
  height: 440px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.product-info {
  display: none;
}
.product-grid:hover .product-info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-products">
    <div class="product-grid">
      <img class="product-image-home" src="https://cardpile.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/blood-rage-460x460.jpg" alt="Homepage">
      <h3>Bloodrage</h3>
      <span>€38.90</span>
      <div class="product-info">
        <p>Some information text</p>
        <a href="link" class="product-overlay-button">CTA</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give some more information

Comment: I believe the reason for that is if you hover the size of your product element is changing so that the layout is not the same anymore. Consider to work on the hovered layout first or you can look at the css grid or css flex property which gives you more control for such layouts.

Comment: You're changing the height of the product to `height: 440px;` on hover and also rendering additional content inside of it. This causes the layout to change. If you want to grow the height, consider doing it on an element that is positioned absolutely within the product so that it is taken out of the document flow.

Comment: Some extra information from my side: What I am trying to accomplish is something like a dropdown menu. When you hover over a product you will then see more information that will not mess with the layout. What happens now is when I hover on a product the height changes and then the other divs will change position. How can I fix this? @LaljiTadhani